# Concurent Access to datastore in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

i want to know if **db.run_in_transaction()** acts as a **lock** for Data store operations
and helps in case of **concurrent access** on same entity.

Does in following code it is guarantied that a concurrent access will not cause a race and instead of creating new entity it will not do a over-write

Is  db.run_in_transaction() correct/best way to do so

in following code i m trying to create new unique entity with following code

```
def txn(charmer=None):
    new = None
    key = my_magic() + random_part()
    sk = Snake.get_by_name(key)
    if not sk:
       new = Snake(key_name=key, charmer= charmer)
       new.put()
    return new
db.run_in_transaction(txn, charmer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a safe method.  Should the same name get generated twice, only one entity would be created.

It sounds like you have already looked at the [transactions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html) documentation.  There is also a more [detailed description](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation.html).

Check out the docs (specifically the equivalent code) on [`Model.get_or_insert`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert), it answers exactly the question you are asking:

> The get and subsequent (possible) put
>   are wrapped in a transaction to ensure
>   atomicity. Ths means that
>   get_or_insert() will never overwrite
>   an existing entity, and will insert a
>   new entity if and only if no entity
>   with the given kind and name exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert Kluin for your help ...
I thought of using it Model.get_or_insert but wondered how will i ensure the returned entity is newly created or an existing one.   
Shall i compare attributes of returned entity with those i want to put.

Comment: You could use your code, or you could compare attributes.  Assuming  two entities created at different times would not also have identical attributes, or if you do not care if they do.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is right and sort of duplicates the [Model.get_or_insert](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert), like Robert already explained.

I don't know if this can be called a 'lock'... the way this works is [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) - the operation will execute assuming that no one else is trying to do the same thing at the same time, and if someone is, it will give you an exception. You'll need to figure out what you want to do in that case. Maybe ask the user to choose a new name?